# PHPmyadmin error on site

Tags: php, mysql, session, phpmyadmin

Without any changes, we suddenly received the following error while wanting to access our mysql dbase via phpmyadmin:

> Warning: Unknown: open(/var/lib/php/session/sess_8i4gv03ka359ktq4tp4h81oufs638cig, O_RDWR) failed: Read-only file system (30) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/session) in Unknown on line 0

Does anyone know why this happened & how I can solve ?

thx
bart

Comment: Change your `/var/lib/php/session` folder permission to `755`.

Comment: @Orion 755 won't help unless you chown the folder to the user running the web server

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your sessions directory is not writable by the web server. This disables your ability to create sessions.

First check that the directory `/var/lib/php/session/` exists. If so, check if it's on a writable medium. Because the message `Read-only file system` makes me a little unsure.

Then make the directory `/var/lib/php/session/` and its current contents writable for the web server. Try chowning the directory to the user that runs your web server. Or (easier, but a bit less secure) `chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session` followed by `chmod 666 /var/lib/php/session/*`

Comment: I might also be caused by the fact the the partition is full. Check the space available first on your disks.